# DB2 connection fails on windows server

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I am trying to create a batch job to fetch some data from a DB2 server. I have downloaded IBM data server client driver and using IBM.Data.DB2.dll. It works fine on my dev machine and performs the required task. However, when I try to deploy this to run on windows server, it fails on the very first line of code that uses the IBM.Data.DB2.dll, I also have the same drivers installed on my server machine. I am getting below error.

```
<Err>   08/05/2022 12:55:00 (Nutra.Logging)    at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.Open()
   at DeliveryDateJob.DatabaseAccess.OpenDb()
```

Here's the code for OpenDb method:

```
public void OpenDb()
        {
            WriteLogMsg(Nutra.Logging.Priority.Info, "[DeliveryDateJob.DeliveryDateJobEngine.Run] - OpenDb method begins");
            DB2Command MyDB2Command = null; //throwing exception on this line
            DB2Connection MyDb2Connection = null;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated, Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Edit: Adding more info-
I downloaded the IBM Data Server Client Packages Version 10.1 Fix Pack 6. I ran the setup and it installed files on the path C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB.
I also ran the testconn command in command prompt on both environments i.e 'testconn20 connectionstring'. It works on my dev and takes some time on the server but works and prints details like .NET Framework version: 2.0.50727.8808 64bit, DB2 .NET provider version: 9.0.0.2, DB2 .NET file version: 10.1.6.2

Comment: Currently the underlying error code (from IBM's driver) is not visible in your question, as if the exception is truncated somehow. Detail exactly what file you downloaded (full filename, filesize, version ), and how you installed it on both the working and failing environment (with administrative rights etc), and whether you did any sanity checking after the installation to prove connectivity with the database outside of c# code.

Comment: Thanks, I edited in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to struggle for days and went though a lot of answers. What eventually worked for me was when I installed the IBM's data server client driver on the server, I unchecked the "Enable Operating system security" checkbox. this was creating a security issue and wasn't allowing me to access the IBM.Data.DB2.dll.
If anyone's facing the same issue, hope this solution helps.